# Best practice when building both RESTful API and web application

Tags: json, laravel, api

So i'm developing a project using `Laravel 5.7`, and I want to include a RESTful API to make the mobile version communicate with the app, and of course the web application itself.

My question is, what is the best practice is such cases when it comes to routing and controllers, I have read some suggestions here and other blogs and got confused, some  suggested that I should declare One Routing file to be used by the web app and API and add an identifier for **e.g("web" and "mobile")** and based on it I return a view or `JSON` data, others suggested to separate the routing (api and web) but point them to the same controller methods which is think it's better than the first suggestion.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Laravel already separates routes into web and api groups for you.  You should read the docs to see the differences, Laravel is well documented.  Best practices are opinion based and off topic for SO.

Comment: Please see http://www.laravelbestpractices.com/#site-header and https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices

Comment: I use the Fat Model approach.  Put all of the real logic inside of models and controllers just point to those models.  I also like to put all of my routes into the API.php file and use passport for authentication.  You can do everything in the web with CSRF token verification but I just like the upgrades security from passport, and it's pretty easy to set up out of the box.  CRUD logic stays in the controller too, just easier and no reason to instantiate a new model for it.  Besides that read the docs and have fun.

Comment: @Devon yes i know that and read the docs, but i got confused when i saw others user different approaches, but anyways Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Egretos will check it out, thank you.

Comment: @BradGoldsmith i followed that approach, i did all the logic for web and api in the controllers and set up the API.php route file, but the problem i'm facing is when using the web application part and i want a view to be returned instead of JSON object, i tried return view("view name", compact("data") and got the view but the URL didn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel  separates the api routes from the web routes.
Web routes are in the `routes/web.php` file.
API routes are in the `routes/api.php` file.

What can be annoying is to separate the logic of the API part from the logic of the web part.
Here the solution is still simple. What I do is I create a folder that I call API in `app/Http/Controllers`; all the controllers I put in this folder are in the `App\Http\Controllers\API` namespace. In the corresponding route file, all you need to do is add the `API\` flag before the controller name.

Comment: yes, that seams the better approach, but is it possible to have the API.php and WEB.php routes to point to the same method in controller without compromising the functionality of the method.

Comment: Yeah, i agress with you, but the difficulty will be the differenciation between api and web returns

Comment: @alihussein There should be no reason to point a web and api route to the same method.  If you find yourself doing this, you're either putting too much logic in your controllers or you should consider consuming your own API instead of building redundant methods.